# org-mode export to LaTeX: Wrapping a section in an environment

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

What's a good way to wrap *every* section in org-mode inside a LaTeX environment when exporting from org to LaTeX?

For example, say, I want to wrap each section in a minipage so that the width is smaller than a line that has been drawn over it.

For this .org file,

```
* Section 1
  - S1 item 1
  - S1 item 2
* Section 2
  - S2 item 1
  - S2 item 2
```

I want the export to produce this LaTeX:

```
\section{Section 1}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item S1 item 1
\item S1 item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\section{Section 2}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item S2 item 1
\item S2 item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
```

Updated to say every section, instead of just one section.

Comment: Cross posted in [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506316/org-mode-to-latex-wrapping-a-section-in-an-environment) which is something I hate to do, but I am at a loss as to where this better belongs.

Comment: It belongs here: it's an Org mode question, not a LaTeX question.

Comment: Re: the revised question - you'll have to write code for that. I would suggest first a `command` (i.e. an [interactive](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/What-Is-a-Function.html#What-Is-a-Function) function) that wraps a region with the desired markup. That could be bound to a key so that you could conveniently execute it: mark a region, press key. That might be enough on its own, but it could also be used later on with something like `org-map-entries` to step through the headlines and apply the function to each one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use special blocks to achieve this:

```
* section 1
\hfill
#+attr_latex: :options {0.95\textwidth}
#+begin_minipage
- S1
- S2
#+end_minipage
```

Comment: That helps, thanks.  Is there a way to wrap every section in an automated way instead of typing it out for each section?  Sorry, my bad - I did not ask my question right.  I have updated it with better wording.

Comment: Different question entirely. In this case, I would create a new latex class for org which uses your particular block instead of "section" or "subsection".

Answer (score 2):

You can add arbitrary LaTeX code to your org mode file like this:

```
* Section 1
#+LATEX: \hfill
#+LATEX: \begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
  - S1 item 1
  - S1 item 2
#+LATEX: \end{minipage}
```

That will produce exactly what you want (plus a label, but that's standard).